# Criação de Caixas

Tags: html, css

Boas pessoal,

Gostava de saber se me consegues ajudar a criar caixas como na foto, não estou a conseguir.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode inspecionar elemento no browser e ver quais os estilos ativo dessa caixa.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nunca me tinha lembrado disso, vou tentar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, se está se referindo a parte estrutural da caixa, você deve inserir Divs no html colocando seus devidos identificadores ID ou Class ae no CSS você estiliza e molda o tamanho.

+- assim como eu fiz.

```css
#omega{
    font-size: 7vw;
    font-size: 14vmin;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    left:25%;
}
.beta{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#58b8ef;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:3px;
}

input{
  width:90px;
  height:70px;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:80px;
}
```

```html
<div id='omega' class='betax'>
  <div id='omega1' class='beta'>1<br>
    <input type="button" value="clique aqui">
  </div>
  <div id='omega2' class='beta'>2
  </div>
  <div id='omega3' class='beta'>3
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Juracer/f905qooa/2/

Comment: já fiz isso, agora o css não está a fazer ligação ao html

Comment: Como vê é possível inserir o código na própria resposta. No editor use o botão `{ }`.